# Center two JLabels beneath each other, vertically

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

I've got to create two JLabels, and the should been positioned center and right under each other in the JFrame. I've beeing using the gridbaglayout from swing, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
terminalLabel = new JLabel("No reader connected!", SwingConstants.CENTER);  
terminalLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP); 

cardlabel = new JLabel("No card presented", SwingConstants.CENTER); 
cardlabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a BoxLayout. In the code below the Box class is a convenience class that creates a JPanel that uses a BoxLayout:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoxExample extends JFrame
{
    public BoxExample()
    {
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        add( box );

        JLabel above = new JLabel("Above");
        above.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        box.add( above );

        JLabel below = new JLabel("Below");
        below.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        box.add( below );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BoxExample frame = new BoxExample();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using FlowLayout and GridLayout**

```
enclosingPanel = new JPanel();
enclosingPanel.setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.CENTER) );
labelPanel = new JPanel();
labelPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2 , 1 ) );  // 2 rows 1 column
enclosingPanel.add( labelPanel );
frame.add( enclosingPanel );  // frame = new JFrame();
setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200 , 200) );
// do other things
```

Using this method you can place 2 `JLabels` in the center and beneath each other. You can also set vertical gap between the 2 labels . [#GridLayout(int, int, int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify proper anchor (CENTER) for the GridBagCOnstraints you use to add the labels to container.

Comment: I think it is center by default. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GridBagConstraints`. Change `gridY` value of constraints while adding second label and it will be placed under first one.

Try this:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    JLabel terminalLabel = new JLabel("No reader connected!");  
    frame.add(terminalLabel,constraints);

    constraints.gridy = 1;
    JLabel cardlabel = new JLabel("No card presented"); 
    frame.add(cardlabel,constraints);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Also read this: [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)